# setup chef with Azure

Tags: azure, chef-infra

I'm trying to test Chef with Azure. I've installed the knife-azure gem and ran `knife configure`.

After that I've downloaded my publish settings file and added it to knife.rb like this:

```
knife[:azure_publish_settings_file] = "C:\chef\.chef\Visual Studio Ultimate com MSDN-Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate-9-25-2014-credentials.publishsettings"
```

Then I ran:

```
knife azure image list
```

and I got this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to find file - Cef.chefVisual Studio Ultimate com MSDN-Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate-9-25-2014-credentials.publishsettings
```

I'm stuck with this error. Does anybody knows why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby (as in many languages) the `\` is used to espace the next character.

Your log is quite clear, it search for a file whithout file separator.

3 solutions:

- escape the backslash using it twice `\\` and your line becomes `knife[:azure_publish_settings_file] = "C:\\chef\\.chef\\Visual Studio Ultimate com MSDN-Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate-9-25-2014-credentials.publishsettings"`
- use the unix separator `/` instead and your line becomes `knife[:azure_publish_settings_file] = "C:/chef/.chef/Visual Studio Ultimate com MSDN-Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate-9-25-2014-credentials.publishsettings"`
- use single quotes arount the string to avoid interpolation, the backslash would loose its special meaning.

I've a preference for the second one.

As mtm commented single quotes are usefull when working on static string and its the prefered style in ruby.

Comment: thank you for your attention and help. PS: I'm not a ruby programmer, that's why I got stuck in this stupid error :P

Comment: Just a note, if you use single quotes `'` for the string you will get a literal `\` rather than an escaped sequence

Comment: @mtm thanks to remember me this. I'm using singlequote when the string is static, but forgot to mention it.